# Get entity by id of sub-class (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

Entities `Topic` and `Users` have a many-to-many relationship. The "table in the middle" is used for a subscription functionality, a `User` can subscribe to multiple `Topic`s.

I'm trying to check if an `User` is subscribed to some `Topic` or not. If `null` is returned, then it means that the `User` is not subscribed to the `Topic`.

This is the structure:

```
Topic.Id = topicId
Topic.Users.FirstOrDefault().Id = userId
```

I tried this:

```
context
.Topics
.Where(t => t.Id == topicId && t.Users.FirstOrDefault().Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is causing this part `t.Users.FirstOrDefault()` i think... If multiple users are subscribed to the same `Topic`, then it's working only for one `User`. It would have to check all `Topic.Users` and not just the `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Then please make your question more clear by providing a clear problem description and all code involved in raising the issue.

Comment: @GertArnold I edited my question. Hope that it makes sense now.

Comment: Not  really. What do you mean by *It would have to check all Users*? Then what's the `userId` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    var isSubscribed = ctx.Topics.Any(topic => topic.ID == topicId 
                                       && topic.Users.Any(user => user.Id == userId));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. `Any()` is what i needed. :)